# Link to database cannot be established: SQLSTATE[HY000]

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to create a simple script for Prestashop 1.6 (`PHP 7.4.5`) which (test) updates quantity for one product combination.

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php'); // path to config

$product = new Product("<COMBINATION_CODE>"); // id of product
if (Validate::isLoadedObject($product)){
    $product->quantity = 5;  // your quantity
    $product->save();
}
?>
```

But when I run this script `php combinations_import.php`, it raises an error and the combination is not updated:

```
PHP Deprecated: Function get_magic_quotes_gpc() is deprecated in /home/web.sk/web/config/defines.inc.php on line 143
Link to database cannot be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

Do you know what should I do?

EDIT

They say I should change host from 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' but I think the DB uses socket.

**settings.inc.php**

```
<?php
define('_DB_SERVER_', ':/tmp/mariadb101.sock');
define('_DB_NAME_', 'db');
define('_DB_USER_', 'user');
define('_DB_PASSWD_', 'pass');
define('_DB_PREFIX_', 'ps_');
define('_MYSQL_ENGINE_', 'InnoDB');
define('_PS_CACHING_SYSTEM_', 'CacheMemcache');
define('_PS_CACHE_ENABLED_', '0');
define('_COOKIE_KEY_', 'xxx');
define('_COOKIE_IV_', 'A6CnQjiY');
define('_PS_CREATION_DATE_', '2017-02-16');
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
    define('_PS_VERSION_', '1.6.1.11');
define('_RIJNDAEL_KEY_', 'xxx');
define('_RIJNDAEL_IV_', 'xxx==');
```

EDIT `/config/config.inc.php`

```
<?php
/*
* 2007-2016 PrestaShop
*
* NOTICE OF LICENSE
*
* This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
* that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
* It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
* http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
* If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
* obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
* to license@prestashop.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
*
* DISCLAIMER
*
* Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade PrestaShop to newer
* versions in the future. If you wish to customize PrestaShop for your
* needs please refer to http://www.prestashop.com for more information.
*
*  @author PrestaShop SA <contact@prestashop.com>
*  @copyright  2007-2016 PrestaShop SA
*  @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
*  International Registered Trademark & Property of PrestaShop SA
*/

$currentDir = dirname(__FILE__);

/* Custom defines made by users */
if (is_file($currentDir.'/defines_custom.inc.php')) {
    include_once($currentDir.'/defines_custom.inc.php');
}
require_once($currentDir.'/defines.inc.php');

$start_time = microtime(true);

/* SSL configuration */
define('_PS_SSL_PORT_', 443);

/* Improve PHP configuration to prevent issues */
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');
ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime', 0);
ini_set('magic_quotes_sybase', 0);

/* correct Apache charset (except if it's too late */
if (!headers_sent()) {
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
}

/* No settings file? goto installer... */
if (!file_exists(_PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/config/settings.inc.php')) {
    if (file_exists($currentDir.'/../install')) {
        header('Location: install/');
    } elseif (file_exists($currentDir.'/../install-dev')) {
        header('Location: install-dev/');
    } else {
        die('Error: "install" directory is missing');
    }
    exit;
}

/* include settings file only if we are not in multi-tenancy mode */
require_once(_PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/config/settings.inc.php');
require_once(_PS_CONFIG_DIR_.'autoload.php');

require_once $currentDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'bootstrap.php';

/* Custom config made by users */
if (is_file(_PS_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE_)) {
    include_once(_PS_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE_);
}

if (_PS_DEBUG_PROFILING_) {
    include_once(_PS_TOOL_DIR_.'profiling/Controller.php');
    include_once(_PS_TOOL_DIR_.'profiling/ObjectModel.php');
    include_once(_PS_TOOL_DIR_.'profiling/Db.php');
    include_once(_PS_TOOL_DIR_.'profiling/Tools.php');
}

if (Tools::convertBytes(ini_get('upload_max_filesize')) < Tools::convertBytes('100M')) {
    ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '100M');
}

if (Tools::isPHPCLI() && isset($argc) && isset($argv)) {
    Tools::argvToGET($argc, $argv);
}

/* Redefine REQUEST_URI if empty (on some webservers...) */
if (!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    if (!isset($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) && isset($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])) {
        $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
    }
    if (isset($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) {
        if (basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'index.php' && empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']).'/';
        } else {
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
            if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && !empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
                $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] .= '?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
            }
        }
    }
}

/* Trying to redefine HTTP_HOST if empty (on some webservers...) */
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) || empty($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = @getenv('HTTP_HOST');
}

$context = Context::getContext();

/* Initialize the current Shop */
try {
    $context->shop = Shop::initialize();
    $context->theme = new Theme((int)$context->shop->id_theme);
    if ((Tools::isEmpty($theme_name = $context->shop->getTheme()) || !Validate::isLoadedObject($context->theme)) && !defined('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_')) {
        throw new PrestaShopException(Tools::displayError('Current theme unselected. Please check your theme configuration.'));
    }
} catch (PrestaShopException $e) {
    $e->displayMessage();
}
define('_THEME_NAME_', $theme_name);
define('__PS_BASE_URI__', $context->shop->getBaseURI());

/* Include all defines related to base uri and theme name */
require_once($currentDir.'/defines_uri.inc.php');

global $_MODULES;
$_MODULES = array();

define('_PS_PRICE_DISPLAY_PRECISION_', Configuration::get('PS_PRICE_DISPLAY_PRECISION'));
define('_PS_PRICE_COMPUTE_PRECISION_', _PS_PRICE_DISPLAY_PRECISION_);

if (Configuration::get('PS_USE_HTMLPURIFIER')) {
    require_once(_PS_TOOL_DIR_.'htmlpurifier/HTMLPurifier.standalone.php');
}

/* Load all languages */
Language::loadLanguages();

/* Loading default country */
$default_country = new Country(Configuration::get('PS_COUNTRY_DEFAULT'), Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'));
$context->country = $default_country;

/* It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings, and this would generate a PHP Strict Standards notice. */
@date_default_timezone_set(Configuration::get('PS_TIMEZONE'));

/* Set locales */
$locale = strtolower(Configuration::get('PS_LOCALE_LANGUAGE')).'_'.strtoupper(Configuration::get('PS_LOCALE_COUNTRY'));
/* Please do not use LC_ALL here http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.setlocale.php#25041 */
setlocale(LC_COLLATE, $locale.'.UTF-8', $locale.'.utf8');
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, $locale.'.UTF-8', $locale.'.utf8');
setlocale(LC_TIME, $locale.'.UTF-8', $locale.'.utf8');
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'en_US.UTF-8', 'en_US.utf8');

/* Instantiate cookie */
$cookie_lifetime = defined('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_') ? (int)Configuration::get('PS_COOKIE_LIFETIME_BO') : (int)Configuration::get('PS_COOKIE_LIFETIME_FO');
if ($cookie_lifetime > 0) {
    $cookie_lifetime = time() + (max($cookie_lifetime, 1) * 3600);
}

if (defined('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_')) {
    $cookie = new Cookie('psAdmin', '', $cookie_lifetime);
} else {
    $force_ssl = Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED') && Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED_EVERYWHERE');
    if ($context->shop->getGroup()->share_order) {
        $cookie = new Cookie('ps-sg'.$context->shop->getGroup()->id, '', $cookie_lifetime, $context->shop->getUrlsSharedCart(), false, $force_ssl);
    } else {
        $domains = null;
        if ($context->shop->domain != $context->shop->domain_ssl) {
            $domains = array($context->shop->domain_ssl, $context->shop->domain);
        }

        $cookie = new Cookie('ps-s'.$context->shop->id, '', $cookie_lifetime, $domains, false, $force_ssl);
    }
}

$context->cookie = $cookie;

/* Create employee if in BO, customer else */
if (defined('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_')) {
    $employee = new Employee($cookie->id_employee);
    $context->employee = $employee;

    /* Auth on shops are recached after employee assignation */
    if ($employee->id_profile != _PS_ADMIN_PROFILE_) {
        Shop::cacheShops(true);
    }

    $cookie->id_lang = (int)$employee->id_lang;
}

/* if the language stored in the cookie is not available language, use default language */
if (isset($cookie->id_lang) && $cookie->id_lang) {
    $language = new Language($cookie->id_lang);
}
if (!isset($language) || !Validate::isLoadedObject($language)) {
    $language = new Language(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'));
}
$context->language = $language;

/* Get smarty */
require_once($currentDir.'/smarty.config.inc.php');
$context->smarty = $smarty;

if (!defined('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_')) {
    if (isset($cookie->id_customer) && (int)$cookie->id_customer) {
        $customer = new Customer($cookie->id_customer);
        if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($customer)) {
            $context->cookie->logout();
        } else {
            $customer->logged = true;
            if ($customer->id_lang != $context->language->id) {
                $customer->id_lang = $context->language->id;
                $customer->update();
            }
        }
    }

    if (!isset($customer) || !Validate::isLoadedObject($customer)) {
        $customer = new Customer();

        /* Change the default group */
        if (Group::isFeatureActive()) {
            $customer->id_default_group = (int)Configuration::get('PS_UNIDENTIFIED_GROUP');
        }
    }
    $customer->id_guest = $cookie->id_guest;
    $context->customer = $customer;
}

/* Link should also be initialized in the context here for retrocompatibility */
$https_link = (Tools::usingSecureMode() && Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED')) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$context->link = new Link($https_link, $https_link);

/**
 * @deprecated
 * USE : Configuration::get() method in order to getting the id of order status
 */

define('_PS_OS_CHEQUE_', Configuration::get('PS_OS_CHEQUE'));
define('_PS_OS_PAYMENT_', Configuration::get('PS_OS_PAYMENT'));
define('_PS_OS_PREPARATION_', Configuration::get('PS_OS_PREPARATION'));
define('_PS_OS_SHIPPING_', Configuration::get('PS_OS_SHIPPING'));
define('_PS_OS_DELIVERED_', Configuration::get('PS_OS_DELIVERED'));
define('_PS_OS_CANCELED_', Configuration::get('PS_OS_CANCELED'));
define('_PS_OS_REFUND_', Configuration::get('PS_OS_REFUND'));
define('_PS_OS_ERROR_', Configuration::get('PS_OS_ERROR'));
define('_PS_OS_OUTOFSTOCK_', Configuration::get('PS_OS_OUTOFSTOCK'));
define('_PS_OS_OUTOFSTOCK_PAID_', Configuration::get('PS_OS_OUTOFSTOCK_PAID'));
define('_PS_OS_OUTOFSTOCK_UNPAID_', Configuration::get('PS_OS_OUTOFSTOCK_UNPAID'));
define('_PS_OS_BANKWIRE_', Configuration::get('PS_OS_BANKWIRE'));
define('_PS_OS_PAYPAL_', Configuration::get('PS_OS_PAYPAL'));
define('_PS_OS_WS_PAYMENT_', Configuration::get('PS_OS_WS_PAYMENT'));
define('_PS_OS_COD_VALIDATION_', Configuration::get('PS_OS_COD_VALIDATION'));

if (!defined('_MEDIA_SERVER_1_')) {
    define('_MEDIA_SERVER_1_', Configuration::get('PS_MEDIA_SERVER_1'));
}
if (!defined('_MEDIA_SERVER_2_')) {
    define('_MEDIA_SERVER_2_', Configuration::get('PS_MEDIA_SERVER_2'));
}
if (!defined('_MEDIA_SERVER_3_')) {
    define('_MEDIA_SERVER_3_', Configuration::get('PS_MEDIA_SERVER_3'));
}
```

Comment: @Amacado thanks but I can't find the "host" in the config - I've added the config at the bottom of the question

Comment: You still need help with this?